# Looping around a list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a hashable list using linear probing.
My hash key is `key%tablesize`

Basically, I can't figure out how to loop through the other elements in the list when a collision occurs. I've written:

```
def hash_linear(key, values):
    tablesize=len(values)
    index=key%tablesize

    if values[index]==None:
        values[index]=key

    else:
        while values[index]!=None:
            index+=1

        values[index]=key
    return values
```

I know that the problem is that the index just keeps increasing but I don't know how to stop the index and start it again when it reaches the last index in the list?

Comment: use the `%` operator the same way you did for index in the first place..

Comment: Side-note: Don't use `==`/`!=` when comparing to singletons like `None`; object identity testing is cheaper and less likely to go wrong: `if values[index] is None:`, `while values[index] is not None:`, etc.

Comment: "I'm trying to implement a hashable list using linear probing" - uh, what? Are you sure "hashable list" properly describes what you're trying to do? Linear probing or other collision resolution strategies wouldn't be involved in making a hashable list.

Comment: I mean like, I'm trying to implement linear probing using a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the following::

```
while values[index] is not None:
    index = (index+1)% len(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo, using the length of your list to wrap around:

```
In [15]: l = [1,2,3]

In [16]: l[4 % len(l) ]
Out[16]: 2
In [17]: l[1 % len(l) ]
Out[18]: 2
```